# Error in storing image link from firebase storage to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to store the link of images that are stored in Firebase Storage into the Firebase Realtime Database.

The link field is not creating in Firebase also attached the screenshot please refer:

MainActivity.java

```java
private void UploadDataIntoFirebase() {

    if(selected_image != null) {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        count++;
        storageReference.putFile(selectedImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Image Uploaded successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        itemInfo.setLink(""+uri.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                databaseReference.setValue(itemInfo);
                // Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Item_successfully_added.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

            }})
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot takeSnapshot) {
                double progress
                = (100.0
                    * takeSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()
                    / takeSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage(
                    "Uploaded "
                    + (int)progress + "%");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ItemInfo.java

```java
package com.example.adminapp;

public class ItemInfo {
   public String name;
    public String price,no_of_items,brand_name,selling_price,discount,link;
    public ItemInfo() {
    }

    public void setSelling_price(String selling_price) {
        this.selling_price = selling_price;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public void setBrand_name(String brand_name) {
        this.brand_name = brand_name;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price=price;
    }

    public void setNo_of_items(String no_of_items) {
        this.no_of_items=no_of_items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return  name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getNo_of_items() {
        return no_of_items;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public String getSelling_price() {
        return selling_price;
    }

    public String getBrand_name() {
        return brand_name;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}
```

***This code is executing correctly but in the Firebase Realtime Database it is not creating the field "link"***

Firebase screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The link field is not creating in Firebase

This is happening because you are adding the "itemInfo" object to the database using the following line of code:

```
databaseReference.setValue(itemInfo);
```

Outside the callback. Firebase API is asynchronous. Any code that needs data from an asynchronous operation needs to be inside the "onSuccess()" method, or be called from there. So the simplest solution, in this case, is to move the above line of code, in the "onSuccess()" method right after:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```